# Drawing, and Appending to a Double-Horizontal Line

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, gdi

I know how to draw straight lines in C#, but I would like to draw a horizontal line, with two colors. Light blue on the top, and dark blue on the bottom. Also, how would I sort of... Append to that line? For example, every few seconds, that line will become bigger... like a ProgressBar. (btw, I'm not creating a ProgressBar, just using that as an example).

Here's the kind of line that I'd like to draw. I am aware that I can simply use PictureBox. But I want to start drawing!

Also, if there are other ways of drawing, than GDI or GDI+, could you list or link to those?

[image: Blue Horizontal Line]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `onPaint` event on any `Control` and then do the drawing manually on the passed graphics object.